# centering text + image CSS

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a footer at the bottom of my page with some text + a couple of png's.

I'm trying to make everything centered. When i try `margin: 0 auto` nothing happens. But I footer is no block element, so that makes sense. Also tried `text-align: center` which only would on the text, but still nothing happens.

Here's the code:

```
<footer>
    <span class="contact"> Made by me - <a href="mailto:test90@gmail.com">test@gmail.com</a></span>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/M3RtrFw.png" alt="Twitter"> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NfLMXs9.png" alt="Google+"> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/oLWJ205.jpg" alt="Facebook">
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

img[src*="imgur"]{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

footer{
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 430px;
}


span.contact{
    font-family: 'Sunshiney', cursive;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also here is the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pS5dW/3/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or do this with your `footer`:

```
footer{
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 430px;
}
```

Turn `max-width` to `width` , then `text-align:center` will take effect.
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pS5dW/6/

Comment: When I changed it from max-width to just width, it worked with text-align like you write :) What's wrong with using max-width btw?

Comment: @Nilzone- Nothing wrong , but in your case you just don't need it. `max-width` is not for elements that their `width` will not change during page' "life-time" , and will stay 100% all the time

Comment: Why didn't the text get centered before I changed it to max-width?

Comment: @Nilzone- It was centered , but footer has `width:auto` by default which means it has minimal width to wrap its children. Try to add `border` to footer so you'll see its size , play with `width` and `max-width`  and you'll see what's exactly happening ..

Comment: Add a background color and you'll see why:  http://jsfiddle.net/pS5dW/8/.  The text *is* centered, but its non-centered container has shrunk to fit the content so you can't tell.

Comment: @cimmanon ah I see. Thanks to you both. One question though. How do i match the footer to my window-size? If you check out your own fiddle and use width:100%, you can slide a tad to the right.

Comment: The parent container (body) has a margin, you'll need to remove it or set the left/right position instead of using a width (`left: 0; right: 0` will do)